# Counterexample for the following statement

Tags: proof-verification, examples-counterexamples, alternative-proof

This question arises trying to solve exercise 14H of Willard's *General Topology* book. That exercise asks us to proof that given any topological space, there exists another space which is Tychonoff ($T_{3\frac{1}{2}}$) such the ring of bounded real-valued continuous functions, $B(X,\mathbb R)$,is isomorphic to the first. The hint given in the exercise suggests us to weaken the topology and then identify points. And that is precisely what I did (you can see my try [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3148307/on-exercise-14h-from-willards-general-topology-book/3148513?noredirect=1#comment6490917_3148513)): I defined a new space in which open sets where those such that:

- They were open in the original space and,
- For each point belonging to this set, there exists a continuous function separating the point and the complementary.

Now, I claim that this operation remains the ring $B(X,\mathbb R)$ unchanged. Below I post my reasoning. I ask you if it is correct (I guess it is not). However, I have tried to find some counterexample, but I have not found any. The one I tried was in the following space:

- $\mathbb R$ with the following topology:
- If $x\neq 0$, the neighbourhoods of $x$ are as usual.
- If $x=0$, then the neighbourhoods are of the form $U\setminus (U\cap\{1/n\}_n)$, where $U$ is any standard neighbourhood.

This space is presented in example 14.2 of Willards book. The author proves it is Hausdorff but not $T_3$; hence neither Tychonoff. However, I did not find any function belonging to the same ring but not to the second.

Here I post my argument:

I have to show is that the set of all bounded continuous real-valued functions remains unchanged. So, suppose that we have removed some open set $U$ of $X$; it is because, at least for one $x\in X$, there was no continuous function separating $x$ and $X\setminus U$. Then, is a continuous function with respect to X still continuous at $x$? Suppose the answer is not, i.e. for some such a function f we can find an open neighbourhood $V$ of $f(x)$ such that $f^{−1}(V)\subset U$. Without lost of generality, we assume that $f(x)=0$; it means $0\in V$. Then, we can work with an $\epsilon$-ball centred at $0$, $W=(−\epsilon,\epsilon)$. But the function

$$\tilde f(y)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\epsilon} f(y) & \mbox{if } y\in f^{−1}((−ϵ,ϵ))\\
1, & \mbox{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

is a continuous function that separates $x$ and $X\setminus U$. It is clear that $\tilde f$ does, and to see that it is continuous, we can consider a net $\{x_i\}_{i\in I}$ converging to some $x′\in f^{−1}(\epsilon)$ (with respect to the topology of $X$); then

$$
\tilde f(x_i)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\epsilon} f(x_i), & \mbox{if } x_i\in f^{−1}((−ϵ,ϵ))\\
1, & \mbox{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

and the net $\{\tilde f(x_i)\}_{i\in I}$ converges to $1$, since f was supposed to be continuous with respect to $X$. So, we have constructed a continuous function which separates $x$ and $X\setminus U$, which is impossible by hypothesis. Hence I conclude that, if $f$ is continuous (in $X$) but for some open set $U$ and some $x\in U$, there is no continuous function separating $x$ and $X\setminus U$, then there is no neighbourhood of $f(x)$ such that $f^{-1}(V)\subset U$. In particular, $B(X,\mathbb R)\subseteq B(X^*,\mathbb R)$ (the other inclusion is trivial because the topology of $X^*$ was finer).

Thanks

---

I would like to mention that Henno Brandsma answered my previous question as it is done in the book *Rings of Continuous Functions*, written by Gilman and Jerison. However, given the hint, it seems to me Willard is thinking on an alternative proof, and that is what I am focused in.

Comment: What is $X$, the Tychonoff space? What is the first space? Not all spaces are nice enough to be a topological ring. Or do you mean that given any $Y$, there is a Tychonoff space $X$ so that $B(Y,\mathbb R)\cong B(X,\mathbb R)?$

Comment: @ThomasAndrew Yes, I meant exactly what you said at the end of your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your construction does indeed leave $B(X,\mathbb{R})$ unchanged.

It is obvious that removing open sets will not add any functions to $B(X,\mathbb{R})$. The only circumstance in which removing an open set will remove functions from $B(X,\mathbb{R})$ is if the open set which is being removed is the preimage of an open subset of the reals under a function $f \in B(X,\mathbb{R})$.

If some open set $U$ is removed from $X$, it is because there exists a point $x \in U$ which is not separable from $X \setminus U$, i.e. if for any $f\in B(X,\mathbb{R})$ there exists a $y\in X \setminus U$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$. Then the preimage of any subset of the reals either contains $x$ and hence contains a point $y$ outside $U$ or does not contain $x$ and hence does not contain the whole of $U$. Therefore $U$ cannot be the preimage of an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I can't believe you. Are you really saying me that my idea was fine? Because after seeing the proof of this theorem and talk about it with Henno Brandsma  I was sure I was wrong. You will make me very happy if you say me are right. By the way, what do you think about my proof? I understand yours, and it's much simpler and much more elegant. In fact, I'm quite annoyed with mylsef because I knew the result you are using. But, do you think my proof actually proves what I wanted, that any continuous function with respect continuous with respect to $X$ must remain continuous with respect to $X^*$?

Comment: I don't understand this sentence: "Suppose the answer is not, i.e. for some such a function $f$ we can find an open neighbourhood $V$ of $f(x)$ such that $f^{-1}(V)\subset U$." 
.

Comment: Well, I think that is because it is wrong. The idea is that I have removed some open sets, so maybe some functions which were continuous are continuous no more. But, given a function $f$ which was continuous, I study its continuity in the ''pathological points'', those where $x$ and $X\setminus U$ couldn't be separable (in fact this is my main doubt: is t enough to sudy continuouty only in these points?). So, suppose the answer is not, i.e. the $f$ we have picked is not continous in $x$ (for $x$ a ''pathological point'')...

Comment: ...The sentence you are asking me for is the negation of continuity in $x$. If $f$ isn't continuous, then there exists a neighbourhood $W$ of $f(x)$, such that, for each neighbourhood $V$ of $x$, $V\subseteq f^{-1}(W)$. However, that doesn't mean $f^{-1}(W)$ must be contained in $V$. It is true I an consider $f^{-1}(W)\cap V$, but I guees $$\{a\in\mathbb R: f^{-1}(a)\in f^{-1}(W)\cap V\}$$ needn't to be a neighbourhood of $f(x)$. Hence my claim was wrong.

Comment: There's a typo in my last comment, I meant $V\not\subseteq f^{-1}(W)$. Moreover, I din't mention it but, if I don't fix my proof showing that actually there exists $W$ such that $f^{-1}(W)\subseteq V$ (which I guess may not be true), it is wrong.